# Xamarin Android Bootstrap

Tags: java, c#, twitter-bootstrap, xamarin.android

I have created a binding library following the steps [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/) for the  Java library [Android-Bootstrap](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap)
The binding project is in [GitHub](https://github.com/MicheldeNostredame/XamarinBootstrapBinding).

After importing the library to the Xamarin Android solution I created the following simple xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Hello" />
    <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapLabel
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:bootstrapBrand="primary"
        app:bootstrapHeading="h3"
        app:roundedCorners="true"
        android:text="Bootstrap Label" />
    <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapEditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:bootstrapSize="md"
        app:bootstrapBrand="info" />
</LinearLayout>
```

However the Design layout is still not applied even after recompiling (see below)

[image]

Any idea from someone who had some luck with it?
Thanks

Comment: In the README-file it says you have to add `dependencies { compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:{X.X.X}' }` to your build.gradle (X.X.X is the version number). Did you add it?

Comment: That's weird I cannot reproduce your issue even if I take your project on Github. Could you please describe more your environment?

Comment: so do you actually see bootstrap-like label and edittext?

Comment: @Nostradamus Yes I do, indeed I see "Bootstrap Label" in white inside the typical blue box of Bootstrap. Which target framework do you use? What is you version of Xamarin? What do you use as player? What is the version of your player? Which version of Virtulal Box do you use?

Comment: @Nostradamus please don't forget to prefix your message with @ followed by my id otherwise I won't be notified, thx in advance

Comment: sure will try and let you know...

Comment: @Nostradamus also which OS do you use?

Comment: I use API 23, what would be the best API level?

Comment: I tested it successfully with API 23 on Google Nexus 5 - 6.0.0 using Genymotion as player

Comment: @NicolasFilotto could you please post as reply your files, thanx. will try to use them and see if I see the same

Comment: @Nostradamus Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 5):

I created a project `TestBinding` that relies on the library defined in your project `XamarinBootstrapBinding`, I built your project and mine with API 23, then I modified the file `Main.axml` of my project to put what you proposed above then I launched my project on `Google Nexus 5 - 6.0.0` using `Genymotion` as player.

As result I see a *Bootstrap Label* in white inside the typical blue box of Bootstrap.

Here are my files https://github.com/essobedo/XamarinBootstrapBinding

Comment: So any news about the test?

Comment: sorry no i cant see it on the regular sdk emulator. not sure if there is any other who have tried and succeeded on a real device

Comment: What is your environment then?

Comment: its api 23, on a regular emulator.

Comment: Which OS? Which version of Xamarin? Which version of Virtual Box? Anything that could help us to help you, as it is working on my side, it can only be an env issue

Comment: FYI...your link is dead.

Comment: @PrisonerZERO that's right, my bad, I unfortunately removed the repository few months ago believing that it was no more used :-(